# How to initialize the value of a sentinel node for a template class?

Tags: c++, constructor, tree, containers, sentinel

Given `Node` in `Tree` container:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Tree {
    struct Node {
        Node(T val) : left(new Node()), right(new Node()), val(val) { /* value node */ }
        Node() : left(nullptr), right(nullptr) { /* sentinal node */ }
        Node *left, *right;
        T val;
    };

public:
    T insert(T val) {
        Node node(val);
        return node.val;
    }
};

int main() {
    Tree<int> tree;
    std::cout << tree.insert(42);
}
```

When I create a sentinel node using `new Node()` it initializes the `val` member using the default constructor `T()`. However, `T`, might not have a default constructor.

How can I create a sentinel node without calling the default constructor of `T`?

Comment: You have several options. The easiest (as far as familiarity with C++ goes) would be to dispense with the need for sentinel nodes

Comment: @StoryTeller, If each node has a color property.  Wouldn't it be better to use sentinel nodes than to do a null check every time the color is accessed?

Comment: @AhmedSaleh Why does `Node` need to also be templated? It is defined inside of `Tree<T>`